# Drupal ExtJS4 (Sencha) integration

Tags: theming, javascript

Has anyone used ExtJS with Drupal? Is there any module for Drupal that supports Ext JS?  If so, what are steps to get it work? I'm wondering if there is any feasibility of creating an Ext based drupal theme.

Comment: ExtJS offers some overlap with jQuery. jQuery is official JavaScript library for Drupal. Putting Ext in would result in numerous problems. What exactly you wish to perform using Ext?

Answer (score 1):

There is just a module that integrates Ext in Drupal that I know of: the [Ext](http://drupal.org/project/ext) module.

> Loads the Ext JavaScript library (version 2.2 & 2.3 for now) with Drupal. Other modules requiring Ext may use this module as a basis, or it may run on its own, simply loading the Ext library.
>
> Note: A new version of this module is being developed to provide relatively comprehensive integration functions with Ext 4.x (currently 4.1). For details please see http://drupal.org/node/1316616.

The module doesn't have a version for Drupal 7, though.